# YARD generates wrong references to files

Tags: ruby, yard, yardoc

I use YARD to generate a doc for ruby project. This project includes a `README.md` file and looks like below:

```
# MyTool

<p align="center">
    <img src="static/logo/mytool.png">
</p>

Welcome to your new gem!

...

## Copyright

Copyright (C) 2019 Company. See [License](LICENSE.txt) for further details.
```

The doc generated by YARD includes this readme file, but it has a litte problem. The paths to the files `static/logo/mytool.png` and `LICENSE.txt` are wrong. The generated `index.html` points to `doc/static/logo/mytool.png` and `doc/LICENSE.txt`, so the link is broken when I click on it.

I tried to move these files to `doc` folder, but YARD generates references like this `doc/doc/static/logo/mytool.png`. Note double `doc` in reference.

I'm newbe wih YARD and ruby. What is the best practice to handle this problem? Can YARD copy this files to doc folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `--asset` option, via `yard help doc` or [here](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/master/docs/WhatsNew.md#added---asset-option-to-yardoc-060). Given your example above, this should do the trick:

```
yard doc --asset static --asset LICENSE.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try it soon.